# I had to refactor a function using the filter() method, but I failed

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, refactoring

The original code of the function was:

```
getGreaterThan: function(input) {
  let greaterValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
  let greaterNums = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < greaterValues.length; j++) {
    if (greaterValues[j] > parseInt(input)) {
      greaterNums.push(greaterValues[j]);
    }
  }
  return greaterNums;
}
```

This is my implementation:

```
return [parseInt(input).filter((greaterNum) => input < greaterNum)];]
```

How can I proceed with this?

Comment: and what is this code supposed to do? and what are your expectations?

Comment: No that won't work. `parseInt(input)` gives you a single number, not an array. The filtering needs to be on the `greaterValues` array.

Comment: If the user types a number lower than 10  the program will count from that number up to 10. // Input: 4 Result: 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

Comment: In order for your code to work, you need to do something like `array.filter( function(arg) { return input < arg; });`. `array` in this context would be your 1-10 array, and the `input` would be a previously defined variable. Start from there.

Answer (score 2):

You should be filtering `greaterValues`, not `parseInt(input)`.

There's no need to put `[]` around the return value. `filter()` returns an array by itself.

```
getGreaterThan: function(input) {
  const greaterValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
  input = parseInt(input); // no need to do this each time through the loop
  return greaterValues.filter(val => val > input);
}
```